# "CocosDenshion/android/SimpleAudioEngine" make error

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am trying to create a cocos2d-x-android demo and I got these errors.

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-18 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml  "  
"Android NDK: WARNING:/Users/linyou/Documents/cocos2d-x/F10Attack/proj.android/../../cocos2dx""/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    

"Compile++ thumb  : cocosdenshion_static <= SimpleAudioEngine.cpp"
"/Users/linyou/Documents/cocos2d-x/F10Attack/proj.android/../../CocosDenshion/android/SimpleAudioEngine.cpp: In constructor 'CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::SimpleAudioEngine()':

/Users/linyou/Documents/cocos2d-x/F10Attack/proj.android/../../CocosDenshion/android/SimpleAudioEngine.cpp:77:2: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]"
"cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors"

"make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocosdenshion_static/SimpleAudioEngine.o] Error 1
```

Can you help me? thanks!

Comment: Have you changed anything in androidmanifest.xml like android-8 to android-18 or in project.properties file. ? seems like you generated a project with minSDK for android-8 api then changed it to android-18.

Answer (score 1):

haha,Nobody know the solution.Today,I have getten the solution. NDK r9 is the builder,the makelog code will be ERRORs. Maybe the cocos2dx team don't take notice of it.Want to fix it, Just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this editing your configuration file

`$PROJECT_HOME/proj.android/jni/Application.mk`

adding this to the compiler flags

`APP_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=format-security`

So you will not get errors caused by that kind of warnings.